# Expose single REST endpoint (GET) which returns a parent object and all the child objects associated with it

Tags: java, api, rest, parent-child

Is it correct to implement one REST endpoint (GET) to expose parent and set of child objects together?

e.g:

> parent {
> name: parent,
> id: 123,
> Children:{
> {
> childName:1
> },
> {
> childName:2
> }
> }
> }

I am thinking two approaches:

1. Implement one API named "parentWithchildren" (GET: /parentWithchildren/)
2. Just endpoint for parent, and it will return a Parent object with set of child objects (GET: parent/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we follow the rest api principles and we assume that your resource is Parent and a Parent can have children. Lets say each child is identifiable by Id as well as the Parent then your rest endpoint will look like:

```
get /parent/{parentId}
get /parent/{parentId}/child/{childId}
```

Now you can potentialy create crude version of your service that is also useful if your children dont have ID than it will look like:

```
get /parent/{parentId}?fetchChildren=true
```

Implementing an endpoint as /parentWithchildren is more of a RPC style of programming, not very rest like.